# C++11 lambdas can access my private members. Why?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, lambda, clang

Consider this piece of code:

```
class shy {
private:
    int dont_touch;    // Private member

public:
    static const shy object;
};


const shy shy::object = []{
    shy obj;
    obj.dont_touch = 42;   // Accessing a private member; compiles; WHY?
    return obj;
}();


int main()
{
}
```

[Live code (Clang)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6b13eda6515cf5e)

[Live code (GCC)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3472bd6bf6d69ca1)

It seems really unintuitive to me. What does the C++11/14 standard say about this? Is this a GCC/Clang bug?

Comment: Why is that counter-intuitive... the initialisation expression for `shy::object` is within the class encapsulation, no?

Comment: @TonyD I guess so, though you could ease my doubt by providing a definitive answer for that. :)

Comment: Maybe 3.4.1/13: A name used in the definition of a `static` data member of `class X` (9.4.2) (after the *qualified-id* of the `static` member) is looked up as if the name was used in a member function of `X`.

Comment: Consider that the classical Meyers singleton is initialized by a private ctor; this is substantially the same.

Comment: @TonyD: You should probably try it as an answer.

Comment: @TonyD Name lookup != accessibility

Comment: Maybe 9.4.2/2 "The initializer expression in the
definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class (3.3.7)." (On a second glance, this seems not so say anything new) The example in that paragraph seems to agree. But better would be some definitive answer about what the initializers of a static data members may access.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As already answered in the comments [@Tony D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410767/tony-d) and [@dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp):

*§ 9.4.2/2 Static data members [class.static.data]:*

> **The initializer expression in the
>   deﬁnition of a `static` data member is in the scope of its class.**

The above means that `static` data members and their initializers can access other `private` and `protected` members of their class.

Also consdering the standard *§ 5.1.2/2&3 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]:*

> **`2` The evaluation of a lambda-expression results in a prvalue temporary (12.2). This temporary is called the closure object. A lambda-expression shall not appear in an unevaluated operand (Clause 5). [ Note: A closure object behaves like a function object (20.9).-end note]**
>
> **`3` The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type - called the closure type - whose properties are described below. This class type is not an aggregate (8.5.1). The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.**

Combining the above we end up to the conclusion that **the prvalue temporary closure object of your lambda is declared and defined in the initializer** of the `static` `const` data member `shy::object` and consequently **the scope of the lambda's closure object is the scope of `class shy`.** As such it can access private members of `class shy`.