# lambda scope for static members initializer

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

My question is about lambda scope for the static member initializers. Consider the following test:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    static const std::function<void(void)> s_func;
};

const std::function<void(void)> S::s_func = []() {
    std::cout << "Hello from " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
};

int main(void) {
    S::s_func();
    return 0;
}
```

gcc starting from 4.8 defines the lambda in the scope of S, so the program outputs something like this:

```
Hello from S::<lambda()>
```

(gcc-4.8.2 has a different definition for `__FUNCTION__` & Co macros, but nevertheless the lambda is still defined within `S`)

Meanwhile gcc-4.7 defines the lambda in the global scope, so the program outputs

```
Hello from <lambda()>
```

Probably newer gcc are more standard-compliant. However I'd like to ask if the standard actually specifies this aspect or it can be implementation-dependent.

**Update**: as @user5434961 suggested that all `__FUNCTION__`-alike macros are implementation dependent, so it's better to avoid them in a standard-compliant test. So here is the example which can be compiled if a compiler defines such lambdas within `S` scope and breaks the compilation otherwise:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    static const std::function<void(void)> s_func;
private:
    static const int s_field;
};

const std::function<void(void)> S::s_func = []() {
    std::cout << "Hello from S::s_func. S::s_field = " << S::s_field << std::endl;
};

const int S::s_field = 1;

int main(void) {
    S::s_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you should change `S::s_field` to just `s_field` in the updated example? Otherwise, I think it always compiles whatever the scope is.

Comment: Well, since `S::s_field` is private, it can't be accessed from the global scope so the code does break the compilation on GCC-4.7 indeed

Comment: Yes, yes. I overlooked the private thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue has been raised before but I cannot find the relevant bug report. Here's a [broken link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/899154/lambda-in-static-initializer-cant-access-private-members-of-class-in-vc-2013) for a MSVC bug report that was supposedly filed (it's still not fixed in 2015: you can test it at [rise4fun](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)). It has however been fixed somewhere between 4.7 and 4.8 for GCC. The relevant standardese used to back this up as a bug is:

> [C++11, 9.4.2/2] The initializer expression in the deﬁnition of a
>   `static` data member is in the scope of its class.
>
> [C++11, 5.1.2/2] The evaluation of a lambda-expression results in a prvalue temporary (12.2). This temporary is called the closure object. A lambda-expression shall not appear in an unevaluated operand (Clause 5).
>
> [C++11, 5.1.2/3] The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the
>   type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type
>   — called the closure type — whose properties are described below. This
>   class type is not an aggregate (8.5.1). The closure type is declared
>   in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that
>   contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

**Previously**

[Why lambda in static initializer can't access private members of class in VC++2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273136/why-lambda-in-static-initializer-cant-access-private-members-of-class-in-vc20)

[C++11 lambdas can access my private members. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237729/c11-lambdas-can-access-my-private-members-why)

[Why is it not possible to use private method in a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933999/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-private-method-in-a-lambda)

Answer (score 4):

I guess it should be in the class scope. Quoted from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (emphasis mine):

> The lambda expression constructs an unnamed prvalue temporary object
>   of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate type, known as closure type,
>   which is declared (for the purposes of ADL) **in the smallest block
>   scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the lambda
>   expression**.

In the out-of-line definition of `S::s_func`, you enter into the scope of `S` the time `S::` is encountered. So, the lambda expression is contained in the class scope of `S`. As the closer type is a member of `S`, access to private members of `S` is granted.

Comment: Thank both you and @user5434961 for equally helpful answers. I marked his answer as accepted since it was a bit earlier than yours.

Comment: @user3159253 You're welcome :) user5434961's answer is better than mine for citing the standard document.