# Is a lambda expression declared in a class a member of that class?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, access-control

Here's another title of my question: *Is private/protected member access in a lambda expression allowed?*

And yet another, *A lambda can access variables from the surrounding scope. What exactly is the surrounding scope?*

---

Facts I know:

- > Class members declared as private can be used *only* by member functions and friends (classes or functions) of the class.   --- [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/member-access-control-cpp?view=vs-2019#member-access-control)
- > A lambda can access, or capture, variables from the *surrounding* scope. 
  >   --- [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019#capture-clause)
- A lambda that captures nothing can convert to a function pointer.

---

In short, below is a code snippet that demonstrates my confusion.

I've tested it on `GCC 7.4.0`(Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL) and `CL 19.22.27905`(VS2019 Community), and on both platform this code has been passed.

```cpp
class A {
    int a = 0;
 public:
    void access();
};

A* getPointer() {
    static A a;
    return &a;
}

void runFunction(void(*fp)(int i)) {
    fp(1);
}

void A::access() {
    runFunction([](int i){
        getPointer()->a = i;  // Here, is the access of variable `a` legal?
    });
}


// Just for running the program
int main() {
    getPointer()->access();
}
```

On one hand, this is legal because this variable is used by member functions(`access()`) the class(Fact 2).

But on the other hand, it isn't directly accessed by that function. Rather, it is accessed in the lambda expression, which is converted to a function pointer.

In this case, the `A::access()` should be similar as this:

```cpp
void lambda(int i) {
    getPointer()->a = i;
}

void A::access() {
    runFunction(lambda);
}
```

This code certainly has syntax error.

And I'm a bit confused.

Comment: What does the compiler say when you try to compile the code? The compiler should know if the lambda is a member function or not and if you can access the private data member. (Solution: it is not a member function.)

Comment: Very related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237729/c11-lambdas-can-access-my-private-members-why Not sure whether to dupe close or not since the questions have different circumstances.

Comment: There isn't any errors or warnings when I'm compiling it. It just, passed compiling.

Comment: OK, now I get it. Strange and interesting! If you want a pointer to the relevant parts from the standard, you might consider adding the tag "language-lawyer".

Comment: @Werner Henze Mayby both are similar, because both lambdas are defined in the scope of the class, even though mine is called outside.